# server request uri trimming parameters

Tags: php

I am using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to get the current url. Then I am passing that url to another page via href.

```
 echo "<a href='second.php?url=".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."'>Click here</a>";
 //the url in this case is index.php?tit=most+wanted&id=23&c_id=11&ran=378834GSF844
```

Then on my second page when I do the below

```
 $mc = $_GET['url'];
 echo $mc;
```

I only get `/index.php?tit=most+wanted`

What happened to other three parameters? is it possible also to get rid of the slash on the front?

Comment: I think you should look at `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_GET` and `$_POST` are for [single parameters only](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` [grabs the entire URL query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the values of $_SERVER.

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

You can see the values and the suitable key you want.
I suggest you use $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] instead of $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].

About the results you have right now, its because of this character "&".
It acts as the delimiter and the next character from that point to the following character "=" will be the a key from $_GET variable and after that is the value.

i think these what you have right now:

```
$_GET["url"]  = index.php?tit=most+wanted
$_GET["id"]   = 23
$_GET["c_id"] = 11
$_GET["ran"]  = 378834GSF844
```

Try using var_dump function to simply see the whole $_GET values.

```
var_dump($_GET);
```